# Laravel Vue JS button not staying disabled on redirect

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a button on my page that when clicked gets the disabled attribute and aria-disabled="true" added on click. However, when the page reloads the button does not stay disabled even though I am passing a boolean true value to is. I added an alert and for some reason even though buttonStat is true I get a false value.

Controller

```
public function syncOrders() {
     return redirect('/orders')->with(compact('orders'))->with('buttonState', true);
}
```

View

```
<sync-button v-cloak :active="{{ json_encode($buttonState) }}"></sync-button>
```

JS

```
<template>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin:5px;" 
     :disabled="isDisabled" :aria-disabled="isDisabled"
     @click="sync">Sync Orders</button></template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['active', 'old'],
        computed: {
            isDisabled() {
                return this.active;
            }
        },
        methods: {
            sync() {
                this.active = ! this.active;

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<sync-button v-cloak :active="{{ json_encode(session('buttonState')) }}"></sync-button>
```